# spork on Win7-x64/ruby1.9.2p0?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, spork

Having trouble getting spork running on Win7-x64/Ruby1.9.2p0:

```
gem install spork

    ERROR:  Error installing spork:
 ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

C:/Ruby192/bin/ruby.exe mkrf_conf.rb
Actually, there aren't any native extensions. I'm just dynamically installing dependencies based off of your operating system

rake RUBYARCHDIR=C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/spork-0.8.4/lib RUBYLIBDIR=C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/spork-0.8.4/lib
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:340:in `bin_path': can't find executable rake for rake-0.8.7 (Gem::Exception)
 from C:/Ruby192/bin/rake:19:in `<main>'


Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/spork-0.8.4 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/spork-0.8.4/ext/gem_make.out
```

I have no problem building any other native extensions (I use the devkit installer from RubyInstaller - have tried both versions of devkit, btw).

I've tried the milhouse-spork gem as well, but it has other problems (missing msvcrt-ruby18.dll, etc.).

Anyone have suggestions on how I can get spork running on my windoze box?  The 30s rails startup for rspec is killing me :-(

Comment: Is the rake gem already installed and working? Can't tell from the message if gem can't identify the directory for the binaries, or if the EXE is not there...

Comment: I can successful install spork following your post. Do I need to restore rake.gemspec file after installing spork?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found that removing the rake.gemspec file before installing fixes this - thanks to my friends at JetBrains for pointing out this fix.